# How do I kill all processes by a specific user from the last 10 hours?

Tags: linux, process

I need a shell script to kill all processes by a specific user from the last 10 hours... I'm a beginner.
however I wrote a script ...

```
#!/bin/bash
Echo “User name : “
    Echo $1
pkill -9 -u ‘id -u $1’ $(ps -eo comm,pid,etimes | awk '/^procname/ {if ($3 <36000) { print $2}}')
```

is this correct?

Comment: Why last 10 hours?

Answer (score 0):

i think it need some modifications, for me i'll write it like that:

```
   kill -9 $(ps -eo comm,uid,pid,etimes | awk '/^PROC_NAME/ {if ($4 <36000 && $2 == UID_YOU_WANT_TO_KILL ) { print $3}}')
```

so the AWK will return the processes id for the user with the id UID_YOU_WANT_TO_KILL and have etimes less than 36000 and name start with PROC_NAME.

Please check it before trying :D